Prove that $\{f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is closed in $C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$
Let $X = C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ with the supremum norm: $||f|| = \sup\{\lvert f(x)\rvert : x \in [0,1]\}$. Define the functions $f_n \in X$ by
$$
f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
  nx & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}, \\
  1 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Show that $A = \{f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a closed and bounded subset of $X$.
My attempt: Since $|f_n| = 1$, the set is obviously bounded. However, I am having trouble demonstrating that $A$ is closed. I have considered using the completeness of $X$ to argue that a limit function of a Cauchy sequence ${f_n(x)}$ must lie in $A$. But, there is no certainty that this limit is indeed in $A$... What alternative approaches might I consider?

You need to show that the limit of any convergent sequence of elements in $A$ must also belong to $A$. Equivalently, show that any element in $X\setminus A$ is not the limit of a sequence of elements of $A$. Indeed, let $g\notin A$, and assume there is a sequence of elements in $A$ converging to $g$. Since $g\notin A$, the sequence must contain infinitely many different elements of $A$. From this it can be deduced (It's not hard, I'll leave it to you) that there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ of $(f_n)$ such that $f_{n_k}\to g$ in $X$.
But this is a contradiction, because $(f_n)$ has no convergent subsequences. Indeed, the pointwise limit of any subsequence $f_{n_k}$ is the function $f(x)=\begin{cases} 
  0, &  x=0 \\
  1, & x\in (0,1]
\end{cases}$ , which is not continuous. Thus, the convergence can't be uniform.

Okay, but isn't it true that the only candidate is the pointwise convergence to the function you mentioned, $f(x)$, which is not continuous and therefore cannot belong to $A$. Would this be sufficent?

@Aristarchus_ Yes, but you have to explain why this is the only candidate, which is what I did in my answer. We need to show that $A$ is closed, which means that any element outside of $A$ can't be a limit of a sequence of elements in $A$. This is not absolutely trivial, as $f_n$ itself is not the only sequence of elements of $A$. You can build a sequence by changing the order of elements, taking repetitions, and so on. We need to prove that any $g\notin A$ is not the limit of any such sequence. This is what I did.

I don't see how you explained that it is the only candidate, what happens when you let $n \to \infty $ in $f_n (x)$?

@Aristarchus_ I don't understand the question. In the last paragraph I showed that $f_n$ has no convergent subsequence in $X$.

It seems like $A$ is closed follows from the fact that $A$ has no limit points (since $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly to some function in $A$).

Note that $(f_n)$ is an increasing sequence of functions.  That is, for any $x \in [0,1]$ and $m \leq n$, $f_m(x) \leq f_n(x)$.  As a result, for any $n_1 \leq m_1 \leq m_2 \leq n_2$ and any $x\in [0,1]$,
$$0 \leq f_{m_2}(x) - f_{m_1}(x) \leq f_{n_2}(x) - f_{n_1}(x) \leq \|f_{n_2}-f_{n_1}\|$$
and therefore
$$\|f_{m_2}-f_{m_1}\| \leq \|f_{n_2}-f_{n_1}\|.$$
[Use this to show that if $(f_n)$ has a Cauchy subsequence, then $(f_n)$ is Cauchy]
Then just note $\|f_{2^n}-f_{2^{n-1}}\| \geq \frac12$, so $(f_n)$ is not Cauchy, and therefore $(f_n)$ has no Cauchy subsequence.
